# Magento CE 1.7.0.2 - Multiple transactions on Authorize.net AND not recording into Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Recently we did a migration from one domain to another after applying a major redesign. The checkout code was not touched during the redesign. We did change all references in DB from old domain to new one. Bottom line is that most transactions are going in fine with Magento and Authorize.net.

However, some transactions are showing on Authorize.net 2 or more times. These transactions show the Magento transaction number and amount paid but when you go and check on Magento these transactions are nowhere to be found. I even checked on the DataBase and the transaction does not exist at least in where it is supposed to be. There must be a trace someplace because the next transaction increments higher than the duplicate one.

I tried what was stated here but doesn't work: http://blog.iuvocommerce.com/magento-authorize-net-frustrating-error-11-a-duplicate-transaction-has-been-submitted/

We upgraded Magento as well from 1.7.0.0 to 1.7.0.2 as well. We are using OneStepCheckout also. But again, we didn't have issues with this before.

**BOTTOM LINE**

Just wondering if anyone experienced such an issue and if so what they did to resolve it? I can't find anything out there specific to our issue here. I'll keep looking around the code testing to see what things could potentially cause the problem.

Best Regards,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem some days ago. Problem occurred because the redesign on dev did not have the coupon salesrule override that allowed for adding promo rules with duplicate codes. Reason why we need to allow for duplicate coupon codes is the following example scenario:

1. User applies code
2. We need to allow for two or more different actions such as:

   a) give 30% off of whole cart

   b) if productx is also in cart make it free

So, the production environment had some rules with the duplicate codes but the redesign development environment didn't have it there. Note that we had two different development environments. One was for the old design so we can do any changes for the production which had the old design at the time while at the same time developing for the new theme design. Then, when we launched the NEW design to production which didn't have that coupon code rule deal and customers began doing transactions Magento would not record the order and Authorize.net would show it duplicate.

Was considering deleting this question but figured I'd answer it.

Best Regards,

George